# How to make curve to snowflake?

Tags: java

It makes half a snowflake. How to make it a full snowflake? Please help so I can understand how to do it. Source code will be appreciated thanks.

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class KochCurve
{
private SketchPad myPaper;
private DrawingTool myPencil;

public KochCurve()
{
myPaper = new SketchPad(600,600);
myPencil = new DrawingTool(myPaper);
}

public void draw()
{
drawKochCurve(6, 300);
}

private void drawKochCurve(double level, double sideLength)
{
if(level < 1)
   myPencil.forward(sideLength);

else
{
  drawKochCurve(level - 1, (sideLength)/3);
  myPencil.turnLeft(60);
  drawKochCurve(level - 1, (sideLength)/3);
  myPencil.turnRight(120);
  drawKochCurve(level - 1, (sideLength)/3);
  myPencil.turnLeft(60);   
  drawKochCurve(level - 1, (sideLength)/3);
  }

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your algorithm "by hand" : perform the mentionned operations on a blank sheet using a simple pen. You'll end up drawing only half a snowflake. That's because the `drawKochCurve` method do not draw all the snowflake edges.